# How to redirect iisstart.htm via command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, cmd, redirect

I'm running iis10 on windows server 2016.
I need to redirect iisstart.htm (default iis landing page) to another url.
Is there a way to do it with command line? 
Preferably powershell / appcmd.

Closest thing I found was this command but it's not what I need cause it redirects any request to this url, and I need to redirect only if no specific web application was requested in the url.

`Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/httpRedirect "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Value @{enabled="true";destination="domain.com";exactDestination="true";httpResponseStatus="Permanent"}`

[image: iisstart.htm redirect]

Answer (score 0):

The only reason IISStart.htm  is the default landing page is because it is configured as a default document.  If all you want to do is redirect to a different file, then use Default Document.   Read about it here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/) but a few scripts:

## Clear all entries in Default Document

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/defaultDocument/files" -name "."
```

## Add new Default Document

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/defaultDocument/files" -name "." -value @{value='MySpecialLandingPage.html'}
```

From the looks of it though, you want to redirect to a folder like OWA.  It may technically be possible using HTTPRedirect (using file specific configuration) but even if its possible, i would strongly not recommend using that feature.  Instead I would recommend using URL Rewrite which unfortunately is a separate download available here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite  In my opinion URL Rewrite should be available on all IIS Servers.

Some good examples of what you can do with URL Rewrite can be found here: https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Otherwise, the specific rule you want I believe is as follows:
1) Match only on URL with no file or folder specified (http://hostname/) only.
2) Redirect those requests to http://hostname/owa/

## Sample URL Rewrite Script

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -name "." -value @{name='RedirectDefaultDocument';stopProcessing='True'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='RedirectDefaultDocument']/match" -name "url" -value "^$"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='RedirectDefaultDocument']/action" -name "url" -value "owa/"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='RedirectDefaultDocument']/action" -name "appendQueryString" -value "False"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='RedirectDefaultDocument']/action" -name "redirectType" -value "Temporary"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='RedirectDefaultDocument']/action" -name "type" -value "Redirect"
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I will look into that and update on what we did eventually. thanks!

Comment: I missed one line and added it just now.  The final line where it sets "Type" to "Redirect".